# GWT / JSInterop / Eclipse Plugin / Production Build

Tags: gwt, gwt-jsinterop

I'm trying to use JSInterop.  My project works perfectly in dev mode.  But when I make a production build it does not work.

In production **and** dev mode, my GWT code **can** access native JavaScript via JSInterop.  However, my GWT classes are **only** accessible to native JavaScript in dev mode.

I had a similar problem in dev mode, when I first started.  But I added `-generateJsInteropExports` to the dev mode config, as shown here:
[image]

I want to add that same command line flag for my production build, but I can't figure out where to put it!

How do I add the `-generateJsInteropExports` command line flag to my production builds in a standard GWT project using the Eclipse plugin?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It was hiding under "advanced" in the GWT compile dialog.  You have to hit the triangle to open that.  Then you see the option to add command line arguments.

[image]